# MySQL - Duplicate column name Error when counting results of a query with joins

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to count the number of results generated by each query that runs on an application that we are building, these queries are dynamic and are generated by the application, therefore we do not have control over the syntax.

These queries turn out to be very heavy sometimes and we need to add limits before executing them, but before adding those limits we need to know the final count.

We fond a very nice way of obtaining the row count of each query without having to execute the results:

```
Select count(*) from ($query) as q_count;
```

Where `$query` is any given dynamic query generated by the application. This works great until the query contains a Join and within the two join tables there is a column with the same name.

For instance, lets imagine the table CLIENTS with CLID (Client ID) and the table Invoices also with CLID (as a foreign key)

The following query returns all the invoice numbers and client names:

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTS LEFT JOIN INVOICES on CLIENTS.CLID = INVOICES.CLID
```

But the moment I try to count them using `Select count(*) from ($query) as q_count` where `$query` is the query above I get the following error:

```
select count(*) from (SELECT * FROM CLIENTS LEFT JOIN INVOICES on CLIENTS.CLID = INVOICES.CLID) as q_count
```

Error:

> Duplicate column name 'CLID'

I understand why this is happening, in the example above I guess CLID becomes ambiguous and count(*) is unable to differentiate between both, my question is for a solution or a way around it, **remember that I don't have control over the queries (`$query`)**

There must be a way because phpMyAdmin is able to calculate the number of results without fetching all the data regardless of the query.

Any thoughts?

Comment: ' obviously these queries are dynamic' - not obvious at all can you clarify?

Comment: @P.Salmon He's writing a general purpose routine and the queries come from the caller.

Comment: You can perform the query and then call `SELECT ROW_COUNT();` to get the number of rows returned by the last query.

Comment: @Barmar I need to know before executing the query, these queries are very heavy and we need to add limits before executing them, before adding those limits we need to know the final result length, thanks

Comment: I suspect phpMyAdmin parses and modifies the query to do what it does.

Comment: In particular, I know that it adds a `LIMIT` clause to the end of the query, and I've seen reports that sometimes it does it incorrectly.